# Graph with $\{a,b\}$ as Vertex Instead of Number

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to create a graph which has $\{a,b\}$ as labels:

```
g := Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   10 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   9 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   7 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can you detect Petersen-Graph-ness?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what style you prefer, I'm showing you how to label both the vertices and the edges.

For clarity, let's define the edges into its own variable:

```
v = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2,  10 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4};
```

Edge label:

```
edgeLabels = (# -> #) & /@ v;
g = Graph[v, EdgeLabels -> edgeLabels]
```

Vertex label:

```
vertexLabels = (# -> #) & /@ Range[10];
g = Graph[v, VertexLabels -> vertexLabels]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enter graph vertices and edges as strings and display using `VertexLabels->"Name"`. For illustration purposes using the graph g provided:

```
graph=UndirectedEdge @@ CharacterRange["a", "j"][[#]] & /@ 
 List @@@ EdgeList[g]
Graph[graph,VertexShapeFunction->"Circle",VertexLabels->Placed["Name",Center],VertexStyle->White,VertexSize->0.5]
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to do this:

```
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
1 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
10 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
9 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4,
7 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,
5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "A", 4 -> "B", 5 -> "A", 
  6 -> "B", 7 -> "A", 8 -> "B", 9 -> "A", 10 -> "B"}]
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Any reason behind the downvotes ?